# How to change width of the select element as per the selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have large list of the drop-down menu.
Some of the option have very large text. and I want to make the width of the selected element as per the selected option.

If the selected option is "Selected" then width should be like 120px or something.
When user select "Very Large Selected option" then widht of the `<select>` tag should be increase.

Here is the sample code, what I am trying to do.
http://jsbin.com/axaka4/edit

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091481/auto-resizing-the-select-element-according-to-selected-options-width

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using some cheating you could clone content of the selected option, measure it's width and resize select to this width like this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $opt = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var $span = $('<span>').addClass('tester').text($opt.text());

    $span.css({
        'font-family' : $opt.css('font-family'),
        'font-style' : $opt.css('font-style'),
        'font-weight' : $opt.css('font-weight'),
        'font-size' : $opt.css('font-size')
    });

    $('body').append($span);
    // The 30px is for select open icon - it may vary a little per-browser
    $(this).width($span.width()+30);
    $span.remove();
});

$('select').change();
```

[A working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5AANG/4/)

Comment: Or add a temporary select and measure that instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385533/how-to-change-width-of-the-select-element-as-per-the-selected-option/6385741#6385741

Answer (score -1):

i have not tested it but i think this should work.i am assuming you have multiselect dropdown

```
 $("selectId").change(function () { 
         $("selectid option:selected").each(function () { 
                str = $(this).width(); 
                $('#selectId').width(str); 
          }); 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that select options' "width" is always zero so you can't do it, nor use getBoundingRect.  Dang HTML!