# Format dropdown width according to selected value

Tags: html, css

The title of this question speaks pretty much for itself.
Is it in any way possible to change the width of a `DropdownBox` to the width of the selected value?

I have searched quite some time on this matter and have not found a good solution so far.
Any help is much appreciated!

For instance with this code:

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

When you select for instance 'Volvo' the dropdown arrow is positioned based on the width of the longest value (see picture).

[image: selected value]

Can it be manipulated that the arrow moves right after the selected value?
Even when they all have variable widths.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hZZ66/)

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/20091481/2454790

Comment: @Jahnux73 This solves my problem indeed. I did not find that question before, thanks