# Adding options to chosen.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I've been having some trouble adding options to a chart.js `<select>` from an array of `<option>`s. I used the same rough procedure all the time, so I'm not sure why it's failing me now...

What I'm doing:

0. I have several `<select>`s which look more or less like this:

```html
<select id='soilname' data-placeholder='Type here' multiple class='chosen-select'>
    <option value=''></option>
</select>
```

1. A sequence of steps that gets me to an array of `<option>`s. This array is called `optnames`.
2. I iterate through the array, adding it to several `<select>`s:

```
for(var i=0; i < optnames.length; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("soilname").appendChild(optnames[i]);
    document.getElementById("soilyearname").appendChild(optnames[i]);
    document.getElementById("albedoname").appendChild(optnames[i]);
    document.getElementById("dcname").appendChild(optnames[i]);
    document.getElementById("acname").appendChild(optnames[i]);
}
```

3. Some distance later, I activate chosen.js:

```
jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen({
    width: "400px"
});
```

I made sure to include all relevant files and plugins in `<script>` tags. I've also `console.log()`ed `optnames` to make sure the array is what I expect it to be. The several other pages on this very topic propose good solutions -- none work. Any thoughts as to what the error could be?

EDIT: some screenshots:

1. The search boxes. They are correctly sized to 400px.
   [image: search boxes upon loading]
2. Clicking one of the text boxes. I added a dummy option manually here.
   [image: What's going wrong here?]

Comment: Is the width not changing to 400px?  Is anything here helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/28308103/3825777 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091481/auto-resizing-the-select-element-according-to-selected-options-width  What's the benefit of using jquery-chosen?

Comment: @Henry Ecker The width is indeed changing, which only adds to the confusion.

Comment: I don't think you meant to ping me. I just fixed the Syntax highlighting on the HTML code block. Did you mean to respond to @jqueryHtmlCSS ?

Comment: Yes, my apologies -- was viewing the edits/comments on my phone.

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Added. I hope they might be useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was going wrong. I was mixing jQuery and JavaScript (something I'm in the bad bad habit of doing rather often). I've now written the code such that it is all jQuery:

```
for(var i=0; i < mynames.length; i++)
{
    $('#soilname').append($("<option>"+mynames[i]+"</option>"));
    $('#soilyearname').append($("<option>"+mynames[i]+"</option>"));
    $('#albedoname').append($("<option>"+mynames[i]+"</option>"));
    $('#dcname').append($("<option>"+mynames[i]+"</option>"));
    $('#acname').append($("<option>"+mynames[i]+"</option>"));
}
```

(`mynames` is the array of strings from which I was originally building `optnames`.) This added all the options exactly as I wanted them. I hope others may find this useful.