# Change size of select tag on option

Tags: html, css

When using select tags, I am running into a problem where my option is greater than the size of the select. I also run into a problem where the option is short and it makes the tag look awkward. Here is what I have:

```
.styled-select-sort {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(http://nightly.enyojs.com/latest/lib/moonstone/dist/moonstone/images/caret-black-small-down-icon.png) no-repeat right #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  font: normal 16px/normal "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.styled-select-sort select {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline:none;
  width: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="styled-select-sort" id="sort" style="width: 85px;">
   <select>
     <option>Example</option>
     <option>aa</option>
     <option>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Here is an example:https://jsfiddle.net/L4erw151/

When you select the one with many a's it goes past the arrow. When you select the short one it looks awkward. Is there a way to shorten and lengthen the width when selected?

Comment: You will probably have to use JavaScript, I'm not sure about a CSS-only solution

Comment: Javascript is fine. Do you know an approach using that?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091481/auto-resizing-the-select-element-according-to-selected-options-width

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/L4erw151/4/

Added function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#sel').change(function(){
    $("#tmp-option").html($('#sel option:selected').text());
    $(this).width($("#tmp").width() + 25);  
 });
});
```

- Removed `style="width: 85px"` from `div`
- Added fake `<select>`