# HTML table row extending based on second row

Tags: html

I have 2 rows in a HTML table. The first column in the first row spans based on the second column(This is Volvo This is Volvo) in the second row.

I want both the rows spanning independently based on the default value/size.

https://jsfiddle.net/p457mcdx/

HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
  <input type="text" placeholder='firstname'>
  </td>
    <td>
  <input type="text" placeholder='Lastname'>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  <select>
  <option value="volvo">This is a Volvo This is a Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: The very simplest way that comes to mind is to simply have two separate tables.

Comment: Would colspan on the second row work for you? If you're only going to have a single element in the second row, maybe that's the simplest solution?

Comment: Is this what you're after https://jsfiddle.net/p457mcdx/1/?

Comment: You can find solution to your problem in the link provided below. Its the same scenario. Thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091481/auto-resizing-the-select-element-according-to-selected-options-width

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width on the select trough CSS

```
select{
  max-width: 100px; /* or width: 100px */
}
```

So that it doesn't span table columns.

EDIT: [Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxjWRw)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder='firstname'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder='Lastname'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <select style="width:100%">
        <option value="volvo">This is a Volvo This is a Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you don't want your select with 100% width, just remove the style attribute