# How do I remove auto-resizing in the select element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue-strap

I want to do the opposite the what OP wants in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091481/auto-resizing-the-select-element-according-to-selected-options-width)

My selects are auto resizing for some reason (probably by using bootstrap, which I have to use). I just want to have a default resizing.

I have two inline select elements and they keep resizing according to the length of the selected option. I want to change their behavior to the default like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocday0a5/). It takes the longest string "United States of America" and sets the elements width according to it.

HTML

```
<div class="flex-top-down">
  <span class="input-header">Doc Type</span>
  <v-select v-model="docTypeSelect.value"
    class="dropdown-default"
    :options="docTypeSelect.options"
    options-value="val"
    placeholder="Please Select"
    search justified required
    close-on-select
  ></v-select>
</div>

<div class="flex-top-down">
  <span class="input-header">Major/Minor</span>
  <v-select v-model="majorMinorSelect.value"
    class="dropdown-default"
    :options="majorMinorSelect.options"
    options-value="val"
    placeholder="Please Select"
    search justified required
    close-on-select
  ></v-select>
</div>
```

I am using [VueStrap](https://wffranco.github.io/vue-strap/#button-group) here to use bootstrap with vue.js

CSS:

```
 .flex-top-down {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .input-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .dropdown-default {
    margin-top: 6px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to use `bootstrap selectpicker` then it can be really easy.

here is example.

**https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#width**