# Is there any way to make select width as long as the current option chosen?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Is there any way to make the width of the option change according to what's being displayed so that the select arrow isn't so far when someone picks one of the shorter options?

```html
<select>
  <option value="all">Choose one</option>
  <option value="1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
  <option value="2">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
  <option value="3">cccc</option>
  <option value="4">ddd</option>
  <option value="5">ee</option>
  <option value="6">f</option>
</select>
```

Comment: with javascript it is possible

Comment: @NikosM. would you be able to expand on that?

Comment: doesnt width: "auto" or "min-content" work?

Comment: @c0dm1tu it doesn't unfortunately

Comment: @0stone0 the selected answer is in jquery which I don't know

Comment: i wouldnt recommend changing its width since will impact other components and probably will overflow outside containers plus is not a good user experience, u can add a fixed width and add overflow: elipsis [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: @illyria I've added [a new js-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71937228/5625547) on the linked duplicate. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming a [jquery answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55343930/1121008) to vanilla js, you need sth like this

```js
function changeWidth() {
  let ghostSelect = document.createElement('select');
  const select = document.getElementById('select');
  var x = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  
  const ghostOption = document.createElement("option");
  ghostOption.setAttribute("value", x);
  var t = document.createTextNode(x);
  ghostOption.appendChild(t);
  ghostSelect.appendChild(ghostOption);
  window.document.body.appendChild(ghostSelect)
  select.style.width = ghostSelect.offsetWidth + 'px';
    window.document.body.removeChild(ghostSelect)
}
```

```html
    <select id="select" onChange="changeWidth()">
        <option value="all">Choose one</option>
        <option value="1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
        <option value="2">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
        <option value="3">cccc</option>
        <option value="4">ddd</option>
        <option value="5">ee</option>
        <option value="6">f</option>
    </select>
```

So what it actually does is that it creates a dummy select with only the selected option, adds it temporarily to the DOM, then calculates the width, sets the original's `select` width to the new width and then it removes the dummy `select` from the DOM.

Comment: It's worth noting that any differnces in the styles of the original `select` and the "ghost" `select` may result in inconsistent results. So make sure to apply the same classes to the ghost element and/or append to the same location as the original (depending on your styling selectors, different approaches may be needed)

Comment: of course. the sample was as simple as the original `select` in the post!

Comment: You can better post this on the marked duplicate so that can be used as a refference.