# Size Bootstrap select element to content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5

I have a `<select>` element styled with Bootstrap 5.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="Schedule.Minutes" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Schedule.Minutes" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.MinutesOptions"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Schedule.Minutes" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using `class="form-control"` so that it has Bootstrap styling like my other elements. However, by default this causes the element to take up the full available width.

In this case, I'd prefer the element only to be wide enough to accommodate its contents (in this case, the longest list option).

Does Bootstrap provide an option for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto resizing the SELECT element according to selected OPTION's width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091481/auto-resizing-the-select-element-according-to-selected-options-width)

Comment: @kmoser: No, I'm trying to do it using Bootstrap 5. I know I could write JavaScript to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the `w-auto` class in addition to `form-control`.

```
<select asp-for="ReportJobSchedule.Subject" class="form-control w-auto" asp-items="Model.MinutesOptions"></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

although Bootstrap utility class `w-auto` can be used alongside the `form-control` utility class to achieve this result,
you can also achieve this by using additional custom styling to make the  element only as wide as its contents.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this using custom CSS:

```
.custom-width-select {
    width: auto !important;
}

<select asp-for="Schedule.Minutes" class="form-control custom-width-select" asp-items="Model.MinutesOptions">  </select>
```

Comment: Bootstrap defines classes for almost everything you could need. The trick is knowing about them, so that you don't end up duplicating functionality. After all, why do you want to bloat your content with functionality that's already there?